# Python: Use of Input() method for debug

Tags: python, debugging

My application (C#/WPF) creates Python code for users who are **not** programmers - they have a selection of drag & drop items and so they create a sequence that the app translates to Python.

That being said, they'd like to add debug capabilities - the option to inject inputs into their sequence during execution (for example, change `myVar`'s value from 1 to 2). From what I understand, I should be able to translate that into Python's `input()`. I've been trying to understand how it works and got the following error(using `PythonWin`):

```
>>> a = 1
>>> input('--:)')
--:)>>> a=2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    a=2
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?
(Also, some tutorial for debugging capabilities in Python - including `input()` will be appreciated.)

**Edit**
We're working with Python 2.6.6. No need for `IronPython` - it's executed in Python environment.

Comment: Is this IronPython? If not, what version of Python? In Cpython 2.x the input() function evaluates user input, but as an expression. So that input is indeed a syntax error for an expression.

Comment: Added details, how can I get around this in Python 2.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input), `input()` method is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))` and `eval()` can be used to evaluate expressions only.

So for example this code is valid:

```
>>> a=1 
>>> input('--:)')
--:) a+1
2
```

but `a=2` is a statement so you have to use `exec()` method to execute it, here is an example:

```
>>> exec(raw_input())
a=2
>>> a
2
```